# How to match part of a text through Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am working on a scraping part through **node.js** and i want to match the part of a text and get the results but i am not able to figure it out. The element from which i want to parse from is:

```
<td title="shell power rate: score for the matched elements" 
style="text-align:right><b>Score-64</b></td>
```

An my **node.js** code is:

```
$('td[title="shell power rate"]').filter(function(){
  var data = $(this);
  score1_SR = data.text();
  console.log(score1_SR);
})
```

So in **node.js**. I am using cheerio library and i want the text output to be Score-64.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^` to match the starting string in attribute selector

```
$('td[title^="shell power rate"]').filter(function(){
  var data = $(this);
  score1_SR = data.text();
      console.log(score1_SR);
})
```